# Unity Login Blank Screen

Tags: unity, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn’t load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Ive installed gnome 3 and gnome3 session . When i login to gnome 3 , it shows gnome 3 panels and my mouse but when i click the menu , nothing happens , it just hang over there . So i decided to remove both package , after removing , i login into my Unity interface and found out that i displays my mouse but nothing else , just black screen/blank screen with mouse . how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of gnome 3, you mean gnome shell I suppose?
  Maybe it's because of yours graphic card drivers. I had the same problem with Maverick Beta, it's because mutter (used by Gnome shell and Unity for compositing) have a lot of problems with some drivers (Mutter is very young). If you use the proprietary graphics of your cards, try to disable them and use Ubuntu drivers. 
  Else, I don't know what you can do except waiting for the Ubuntu 11.04 version of Unity wich will use compiz instead of mutter (it means a very very very better compatibility).
  Firsts versions of compiz based Unity should be available soon in a ppa to test, but beware, it will be devellopement version)