# Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears

Tags: unity

When I login, nothing happens.

I am presented with my desktop wallpaper.

[image: Blank desktops suck]

No Dash, no Launcher, nothing.

Comment: IMHO this is a bug, but I have this since today.
Could only find this bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1212987 I followed the recommendations here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/286349#286349 Unity did reset but is not working OK, workspaces don't work, even if I enable or disable or change amount. No difference. Put plugin also crashes unity,

Comment: My problems started after switching from nouveau drivers to NVIDIA drivers (system settings / hardware tab).

Comment: i had this problem because my hard drive had filled up without my realising it. clearing up some space let me get into the desktop again.

Comment: After many spent days and many SO threads read, I found that this seems to be an Ubuntu open Bug (Status 'Incomplete' as of Juli 2015). More information about it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1285444
 The quick solution seems to be:  `$ mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old`

Comment: The only thing which worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04) was to create a new user from the command line and run startx in a hard terminal (I couldn't even login with GUI) to login with that new user (after startx, guest user would also work fine).

Comment: @julianromera's was the only solution on this thread that helped me

Comment: @julianromera answer was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: I solved opening the terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get -f upgrade`, `sudo apt-get --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity`, `sudo service lightdm restart`

Answer (score 484, accepted):

> ### This answer applies to versions of Ubuntu running Compiz.
>
> This answer assumes Unity is being run through Compiz. If you don't have [compiz installed](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=compiz&searchon=names) (ex: on non-Unity versions of Ubuntu, such as the Gnome-based Ubuntu 18.04 and later) this answer doesn't apply to you.

You just need to turn the Unity plugin back on. The problem is this is a pain in the bottom because you've now got no graphical method to do this. So:

1. Try to open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
   This may not work but you can try right clicking on the desktop and selecting "Open terminal here." Otherwise, you may need to change to a "hard" terminal by pressing
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.
2. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` by running

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
3. Then run it with this:

   ```
   DISPLAY=:0 ccsm &
   ```

   The first part tells the terminal which display you want it to load on (otherwise it won't have a clue).
4. If you switched to a TTY in step 1, switch back to the graphical server by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> sometimes).
   There there should be a CompizConfig Settings Manager waiting for you.
5. Find the Unity plugin. Enable it (detailed instructions just below). You will be asked "Ubuntu Unity Plugin requires the plugin OpenGL. Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin / Enable OpenGL"

   - **1) To enable the Unity Plugin:** Click "Desktop" (left side) --> Ubuntu Unity Plugin. You can also type "unity plugin" into the "Filter" search box. Screenshot: 
     [image]
   - From here, click the checkbox for "Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin":
     [image]
   - **2) To enable OpenGL:** click "General" (left side) --> then check the box for "OpenGL", as shown below. You can also type "opengl" into the "Filter" search box to bring it up.
     [image]
6. Everything should spring into life but if it doesn't, you might have to restart. You can do that by going back to the terminal and running `sudo reboot`.

Comment: I just got the same issue (thanks for the answer). In CCSM I saw that _all_ my plugins had been removed. Any idea why such a thing could have happened?

Comment: (But none of the answers here got it back, nevertheless)

Comment: Worked perfectly well for me. As a side note, I did not need to enter the TTY terminal, was able to use the terminal shortcut (`ctrl + alt + t`).

Comment: In fact this is what I used to get rid of unity and now my desktop is super minimalistic. I installed gnome-do and few keyboard shortcuts and it works awesome without any wastage of screen real estate.

Comment: If you get to step 5 and don't see unity on the list, try this: `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity`

Comment: For me some parts of the window manager again crashed after I first enabled the unity plugin, during which I was asked to also enable required dependencies such as the plugins 'scale' and 'expo'. It helps to always keep a terminal open. Then one can try to restart the window manager by typing `compiz &` in that terminal and then repeat to enable the unity plugin.

Comment: Had this problem myself but I'm unlucky with the solution far, doesn't work for me, still get the same empty screen on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit. Will go over the steps again to check if any thing was missed. Lenovo X201S Thinkpad i7 2.0Ghz 8Gb RAM. Never had this issue with 12.04 LTS

Comment: Tip: @Shahbaz For me, I found that the original problem was for one of my accounts. When I logged into another account everything was normal. So my approach to the problem would be to move any valuable personal files from the faulty account to the working account, delete the faulty account and the recreate it and move the files back.

Comment: I had this problem and it was because the unity plugin got deactivated somehow. Using ccsm, selecting the unity plugin and putting a check in the box to enable it did the trick for me.

Comment: The fact that this is problem so common and long-lasting is, to me, rather disturbing.  Does anyone know why this keeps happening, and what's causing it?

Comment: This solution doesn't work, I can only log with one of my accounts on atrl-alt-f7, with the others I'm kicked out. My pc has become almost useless. No solution in this page has worked.

Comment: This solution does not work for me.   This really should have been added to an existing answer in order to improve it!  http://askubuntu.com/a/18996  as should many of the other suggestions/answers :)

Comment: We just used your answer in class to get back Unity that professor borked after messing with a bunch of things :)

Comment: This (partially) worked for me, thanks!  What's still messing is the menu bar with the controls for sound, networks, etc.

Comment: ccsm hangs on Loading Icons, but if I ctrl-alt-F7 back to the main display, the compiz options ARE there. I've enabled the Unity desktop, switched back to tty1 (ccsm has executed successfully)... but no Unity. Reboot: no Unity. If I reload ccsm, Unity is still selected and "on" but no Unity appears.

Comment: is this a good solution if we have a NVIDIA linux grafics card driver installed? Thanks for that. I heard, that compiz might conflict with that?

Comment: There is no unity setting for me. And is everything in compiz supposed to be disabled? It was by default

Comment: Yesterday my Ubuntu 15.10 was working, today it got stuck in a login loop after installing uodates. (I thought only Windoze did this). The compiz config setting manager seems to have worked for me.

Comment: @Oli I did what you recommended above and got the unity launcher but I have to drag the  cursor there to display it,means It is not continuous displaying Unity launcher how can I fix it.

Comment: god bless your soul! @Oli

Comment: @Oli Such a really Good Answer i have fixed my issue thank you so much ..

Comment: Without GUI how we can connect to internet?? How we can install compiz manager without connect to internet.. Please.. Can anyone explain the process..

Comment: I have been stopped in step 3.  It is saying "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 "

Comment: Should this be possible in Lubuntu 14.04 as well? It doesn't seem to be for me. Have tried all steps, but even after installing Unity and checking it's enabled I don't get anything on desktop. Is there an alternative for Unity for Lubuntu?

Comment: @Ingrid No. Lubuntu doesn't use Compiz so unless you've added it, it's unlikely to help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not applicable to Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I agree with Luis de Soussa. I'm also using 16.04. I cannot get my taskbar or the titlebar/system bar to show at all using this method.

Comment: I tried followi g this solution for 16.04 LTS. It doesn't seem to apply the settings when I enable the Unity Plugin. I try a second time, and the checkbox is unchecked! Any ideas why?

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. My main system is running ubuntu and if I had not gotten this up I probably would have lost more than a ubuntu installation

Comment: I try this `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity`

Comment: Its working only once for me, when I restart, I'm back to the same issue.

Comment: @jvriesem how did you solve the problem? I can't enable the Unity plugin as well.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota I didn’t fix it. I stopped using Linux for many months in frustration. :-(

Comment: I get `ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Reference_Face`

Comment: For everyone with Ubuntu 16.04 or get the "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1" problem like I did, the solution you are looking for is likely way down here: https://askubuntu.com/a/827296/452147

Comment: **How do you know if you have compiz installed? Adding how to know if you have compiz installed to the top of this question would be very helpful.** I initially glossed over this answer because I don't know what compiz is and didn't know if I have it. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. Apparently I have it installed, so this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 174):

A solution good for me (has solved the same problem):

in a terminal:

```
export DISPLAY=:0   
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

and then

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: Yep, works great with 13.10 too, greatly resets the buggy hud

Comment: Fantastic. Works with Ubuntu Linux 13.04 Desktop in Parallels on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks! Works with Ubuntu 14.04 too. I wonder why this happened out of the blue though :-(

Comment: I needed `export DISPLAY=:0` first.

Comment: The first command did the trick for me. (Had to additionally `export DISPLAY=:0` and set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable as outlined in http://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell)

Comment: ERROR: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded. What does it mean?

Comment: Worked perfectly for me..

Comment: sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autholaunch=c0c0f8bf86119c64ccb710000000006 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': child process exited with code 1

Comment: this worked for me on 14.04

Comment: Thanks! This really dug me out of a hole. Just to add that if like me, Unity had lost the ability to run a terminal with ctlr+alt+t, then just type ctrl+alt+F1, and drop into a command line screen, log in and follow the instructions given in this answer. Good luck!

Comment: I had to run `export DISPLAY=<HOSTNAME/IP>:0` following the answer on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199891/invalid-mit-magic-cookie-1-key-when-trying-to-run-program-remotely

Comment: I was able to rescue my wife's 16.04 beta system with `DISPLAY=:0 sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` from TTY1

Comment: this solved my problem, the accepted solution does not solve my problem, infact compiz make all my window border gone because of some conflict with "theme corations" and "gnome theme", i think there is 2 different problem that produce similar symptoms, and this solution and the accepted solution fix different area of the problem

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04.3 this method does exactly nothing.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 this method brings the launcher back, but not the dash, nor the desktop. Also, all the theming settings are lost.

Comment: One issue with this is that running `dconf` as `sudo` made my `~/.config/dconf/user` file have `root` ownership (it had my user ownership before).  I'm wondering if it should be done without `sudo`.   This was much better than removing the file and starting from scratch!

Comment: working at 16.04

Comment: This worked for me... Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: For everyone with Ubuntu 16.04 or get the "Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autholaunch=c0c0f8bf86119c64ccb710000000006 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': child process exited with code 1" problem like I did, the solution you are looking for is likely way down here: https://askubuntu.com/a/827296/452147

Comment: Worked with me in Ubuntu 16.04 running inside VirtualBox

Answer (score 76):

### In 13.04 and 14.04:

`unity --replace` is deprecated. Instead, use the following:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

Reboot if it doesn't work right away.

Comment: This worked for me after installing appropriate drivers for my Nvidia graphics card. See my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/288235/launcher-and-panel-missing-ubuntu-13-04/289498#289498

Comment: `dconf reset` command gives exitcode error 1 and won't work on `13.10`.

Comment: works when I ran at the second time `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && unity --reset-icons &disown`

Comment: I'm again stuck at `Initializing core options...done`.. how long should I wait for this to complete?!

Comment: @rusty should be instantaneous. If none of these fixed your issue I would recommend opening a new question.

Comment: enabling Unity plugins with `ccsm` fixed some of the problems, the rest were fixed with `rm -r .Xauthority .ICEauthority .compiz-1/ .gconf/ .config/compiz-1/ .config/dconf/`

Comment: Were you using a program that messes with Unity's settings like Unity Tweak at some point?

Comment: The slash after compiz is REALLY important.

Comment: Cannot autolaunch D-bus without X11 $DISPLAY. 
Nothing worked so far

Comment: @jimifiki I had the same problem because I rebooted between previous instructions and these.  Try `export DISPLAY=:0` first, then try these instructions again.  Of course, I got a core dump when I did the `unity --reset-icons &disown` so maybe that doesn't help.

Comment: It works for ubuntu 16.04 also , just resolved my issue

Answer (score 62):

#### For 12.10 and below:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for a terminal and run `ccsm`, then re-enable your 'Unity' plugin.

You also may then need to run a `unity --replace`.

Comment: `unity --reset` is deprecated now and doesn't work. Is there a replacement?

Comment: @Shahbaz - `unity --replace`.

Comment: @nerof61 also deprecated as of 13.04. See my answer below: http://askubuntu.com/a/286349/2638

Comment: neither `--reset` nor `--replace` worked for me with my Ubuntu 12.04 ..running the commands instantly displayed `unity-panel-service: no process found
Backend     : ini
Integration : true
Profile     : default
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done` ...I waited and waited, and then I couldn't, interrupted with ctrl + c.. and now looking to try what other answers suggested..

Answer (score 54):

It is a good idea to check your graphics driver is configured to use hardware acceleration and it is configured to use OpenGL.  Try searching Ask Ubuntu and Ubuntu Forums for information specific to your GPUs and Ubuntu flavour.  For hybrid graphics users see the last section "Hybrid Graphics" below.

You might want to run the [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] package and make sure that the Unity plugin is checked (see [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](/q/80589)).

### For 12.04 And Newer

1. Change to `tty1` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.
2. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` by running

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
3. Then run it by doing this:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   ccsm
   ```

   The first part tells the terminal which display you want it to load on (otherwise it won't have a clue).
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> sometimes) to get back to the graphical display where there should be a CompizConfig Settings Manager screen sitting there.
5. Find the Unity plugin. Enable it. [image: CCSM]
6. Everything should spring into life but if it doesn't, you might have to restart. You can do that by going back to `tty1` and running `sudo reboot`.

If unity still does not load try:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

Reboot if it doesn't work right away.

### For 11.10 And Older

If you hope into a TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd>) and run:

```
DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace
```

It will reset Unity back on TTY 7 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt+</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>).

You can also try just:

```
DISPLAY=:0 unity
```

But that won't work if a windows manager is already running on display 0 (it will give you an error, just use `unity --replace` in that case).

If Unity *absolutely* refuses to restart try this:

Install `gnome-panel`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

Than run it on display 0:

```
DISPLAY=:0 gnome-panel
```

You should then have Gnome 2 style panels on your desktop, which you can use to logout.

### Hybrid Graphics

Some very useful information and further reading for hybrid graphics users can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/hybrid_graphics).

Once GPUs are configured appropriately for 3D acceleration and OpenGL you can:

1. Install Nvidia drivers from https://edge.launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa:

   ```
   sudo apt-add repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
   ```

   **or:**

   I would really prefer the [stable PPA](https://edge.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates), <del>but it does not seem to have packages for 13.04 yet</del>. Update: these seem to be available as of Sep. 25. I would install this stable PPA - you can try but I have not tested it.

   The Ubuntu-supplied Nvidia drivers were already installed and I simply installed from this PPA by adding it and doing a package update using `update-manager`.

   ```
   sudo apt-add repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   ```
2. Install Bumblebee from https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/stable

   UPDATE: As of Oct. 6, `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` seems to contain bumblebee as well. So if you install from this PPA, you might want to try skipping the addition of the Bumblebee PPA and installing it from here instead.

   If you chose the stable PPA in step 1, install the Bumblebee stable PPA as follows:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
   ```
3. UPDATE: After adding the PPA(s), update your package lists:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   If you already had nvidia drivers installed from Ubuntu's standard repositories, simply upgrade to get the new version from the repository chosen in step 1:

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get install bumblebee
   ```
4. Perform the following commands to 'repair' Unity (from [brandon-bertelsen](https://askubuntu.com/users/2638)'s answer to [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](/q/17381)):

   ```
   dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
   unity --reset-icons & disown
   ```

Comment: In 14.10: unity --reset-icons &disown gives me stop: Unknown job: unity-panel-service // start: Unknown job: unity-panel-service // compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core // compiz (core) - Info: starting plugin: core ... and no further action. Alt-F7 takes me back to graphical where I have a side menu but no "start" menu (nothing on the top menu -- no connectivity icon, power icon, etc. -- back to tty1 gives me screens and screens of information ... reboot and I am BACK IN BUSINESS! THANK YOU FOR YOUR MAGIC VOODOO

Comment: Your "For 12.04 and newer" section does not work on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: apt-add-repository ? - missing

Answer (score 34):

The easiest way to do this is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to get a terminal and then issue:

```
rm -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1
```

and your unity session will come back before your eyes..

This technique is better than re-launching ccsm, because you can get into OP's error condition without even accidentally de-selecting unity in ccsm; you can get it simply by accidentally pressing the "preferences" button in ccsm.

Comment: guess you mean .config/compiz-1

Comment: I cannot use ctrl-alt-T

Comment: @jimifiki: press 'crtl' + 'alt' + 'f1' and then do what achiang suggested. though personally I'd move them out of the way incase you find more problems.

Comment: @isaaclw I did what suggests. Nothing has changed. Remarkably the guest session works normally.

Comment: I've seen this so often, and not every time I was able to solve it by just removing compiz configurations in the user's profile.

Last time I wasn't able to even reinstall anything, as suggested on other comments, because even the network configuration was all screwed up.

I issued an `apt-get check` and got a message stating that there was something broken up during a previous install or such, but with clear instructions on how to fix it (it was a `dpkg <something>` command I can't recall exactly now).

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me (64-bit 14.10 with nVidia)!  You should clarify for people that this deletes your launchers and other customizations you may have made with compiz.  Thanks!

Comment: Not a solution for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: That one worked for me with 16.04.  Thanks!

Comment: Did not work for me on  16.04

Comment: For my Ubuntu 16.04, the relevant files to remove were in `.cache`, not `.config`. So `rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1` worked for me.

Comment: That helped me only after I fixed another issue described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/534135/how-to-fix-unity-locked-disabled-settings

Answer (score 24):

I had this problem too. I solved it with deleting the content of the ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig file and relog.

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
```

Comment: didn't work for me, pretty much as everything else on this page

Comment: Yes! Thank you, It worked! I have Ubuntu **16.04** installed in VirtualBox and after one of the updates I got this problem. **This is the only solution that worked for me!** Oh, and don't forget to restart after applying this fix.

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did not work for me on 16.04

Comment: This worked for me after reboot. Hopefully it stays that way. Thank you :)

Comment: It was on 16.04 that this worked for me

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04. But why tho?

Comment: For my Ubuntu 16.04, the relevant files to remove were in `.cache`, not `.config`. So `rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1` worked for me.

Comment: The removal of `.cache/compizconfig-1` worked for me as well on Ubuntu 16.04. I recently had updated my libraries after a while and this was the first time I had logged back in.

Comment: This worked for me on 16.04.5 after trying all the higher voted answers on this page.

Answer (score 22):

I have had exactly the same issue.

If you have Compiz Config Settings Manager installed it may be that the Unity Desktop Plugin is disabled.

Log in to a Unity 2D desktop and check that it is enabled in CCSM like this,

[image: CCSM]

Unity Shell will not load in the default desktop if the tickbox is not checked and you will get the session in your picture.

Answer (score 20):

Developers are always fixing bugs, so an alternative is to wait, and to follow progress on bug fixing ([subscribe to Unity development in Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/4.0)).

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
2. Log in.
3. Run `sudo shutdown -r now` in a terminal.
4. At the login screen after your system restarts, choose Unity 2D (for now)
   by right-clicking the sprocket icon.
5. Wait for a fix for Unity 3D/Ubuntu 11.10  (e.g. a week).
6. Update your system to get the fix; in a terminal type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

**UPDATE:** I was able to resolve this by using `ccsm`, from Unity 2D login.

(This is adapted from [this Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11319786&postcount=15).)

1. At the login screen, select Unity 2D and login.
2. Install `ccsm` (CompizConfig Settings Manager) by running in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`.
3. Start `ccsm`, and select the category *Desktop*. Enable the *Ubuntu Unity Plugin*; if asked to resolve conflicts, select the MIDDLE button for all conflicts. Close `ccsm` when done.
4. Restart, select Unity (3D) and login.

Answer (score 14):

I have an Asus U36SD using an "Optimus" (Intel + Nvidia GPUs) set-up. I had Ubuntu 12.04 working just fine, but upgrading to 12.10, this problem appeared and persisted in 13.04.
I have managed to fix it trough the following steps:

1. Install Nvidia drivers from https://edge.launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa.

   OR:

   I would really prefer the stable PPA at https://edge.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates, <del>but it does not seem to have packages for 13.04 yet</del>. Update: these seem to be available as of Sep. 25. I would install this stable PPA - you can try but I have not tested it.

   The Ubuntu-supplied Nvidia drivers were already installed and I simply installed from this PPA by adding it and doing a package update using `update-manager`. UPDATE:

   ```
   sudo apt-add repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
   ```

   (what I did) or:

   ```
   sudo apt-add repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   ```

   (stable release for 13.04 too now - not tested by me).
2. Install Bumblebee from https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/stable

   UPDATE: As of Oct. 6, **ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa** seems to contain bumblebee as well. So if you install from this PPA, you might want to try skipping the addition of the Bumblebee PPA and installing it from here instead.

   If you chose the stable PPA in step 1, install the Bumblebee stable PPA as follows:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
   ```
3. UPDATE: After adding the PPA(s), update your package lists:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   If you already had nvidia drivers installed from Ubuntu's standard repositories, simply upgrade to get the new version from the repository chosen in step 1.:

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

   Install Bumblebee

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bumblebee
   ```
4. Perform the following commands to 'repair' Unity (from [brandon-bertelsen](https://askubuntu.com/users/2638/brandon-bertelsen)'s answer to [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/)):

   ```
   dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
   unity --reset-icons &disown
   ```

Comment: I just needed to perform the last step of your answer because I have the nvidia card deactivated in bios and never used it but the dconf reset worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This happened to me just now after an update and the last step was enough for me too.

Comment: how do you install that stuff from those links while having no launcher and being even unable to move windows around? I've tried skipping that step but it does not work for me. Can you give command-line instructions for adding those ppa's and installing those things?

Comment: I added some details above - hope it helps.

Answer (score 13):

The original poster of the duplicate question, solved in editing his own question:

> **Solution found :** Delete .Xauthority in my home (or rename it)

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
```

Comment: This is so great!

Answer (score 13):

This happened to me as well in **Ubuntu 16.04** after an upgrade of unity and compiz packages. None of the above worked.

The only way I found to have launchers and dashes back was to remove (while NOT logged into Unity) the directory **.cache** in my home.

Comment: Thanks, having tried so many other solutions in vain (`ccsm`, resetting, deleting config dirs etc.), this solved the problem for good!

Comment: This is often the case if you jiggle with drivers, GPU's and all...  deleting .cache will do the job.

Comment: Worked for me too (Ubuntu 16.04). Something upgraded when I last shut my machine down. When it started back up, Unity wasn't loading. I tried many of the steps above, and none of them worked. This simple step of deleting ~/.cache did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This happened to a friend running 16.04. I resolved it by upgrading her to Ubuntu 18.04, using the new Gnome desktop instead of Unity.

Answer (score 11):

## For 13.10:

Just to insure everything is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity ubuntu-desktop
```

Next, reload everything:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && unity --reset-icons &disown
```

I just tried this and it works!

Source:

https://askubuntu.com/a/204784/54037

## If all else fails:

Remember, always make backups! However, sometimes a fresh install is good, reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: The 'if all else fails' is a bit useless... see also: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11710/lets-not-do-i-dont-know-how-to-fix-your-problem-so-just-reinstall?cb=1

Comment: @Wilf Fresh installs are never useless. Most people have a poor install or simply mess up their installation. Time for refresh.

Comment: yeah, especially with upgrades... I have found that `apt` seems to have developed the knack of removing `unity` to to wacky interpretations for regular expressions (e.g. nuking webapps) - checking whether unity is installed/installing anything that is missing can then be helpful,

Comment: This worked after a lightdm restart :D. Thank you, I tried dpk-reconfigure but looks apt-get --reinstall is better in this case.

Answer (score 9):

It seems there's a problem with 12.04 Unity 3D and the current Nvidia drivers.

See [this post (Unity 3d no longer works after installing 12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125608/unity-3d-no-longer-works-after-installing-12-04) for details of how to work round the problem.

I have a 32 bit Pentium 4 3.06 GHz Compaq D520SFF, with an Nvidia GeForce 6200, running kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae, and had exactly the same problem (2D works, 3D doesn't), and downgrading the Nvidia drivers got 3D working for me in a couple of minutes.

Comment: i did almost all the answers in this community related to my issue..please give me some thing work...

Comment: Almost all is a vague phrase.... Have you actually tried downgrading the NVidia drivers from 295.40 to 295.33 as described in the post?

Comment: i did all described by the post nothing happened...

Answer (score 9):

For the icons, it is due to Nautilus. Write `nautilus &` in a terminal, **do not close it**, and the icons will be back.

**EDIT 10/10/2013**: for Nautilus you can also type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to open Unity command line prompt and write `nautilus` in the global search/prompt CLI. A file explorer will open. You can close it if you want.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem:

unity with 14.04 in combination with IBM Notes9 resulted in some strange behavior (mouse clicks would stop working). My workaround for that was to open a terminal and restart unity by typing `unity &`.

The last time I did that, it totally corrupted unity - the no dash, no launcher no nothing. 
I think I tried EVERY suggestion that is listed on this page - none of it did help.

But a coworker finally had the answer that worked for me:
I installed the unity-tweak-tool; than I ran `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` and rebooted.

Afterwards, unity was back alive. Obviously all prior configuration changes to unity were gone, but that is what `--reset-unity` is about.

And the big advantage of this solution: it requires you to only add a single package and to redo your unity config changes - but you do not have to reset compiz, install ccsm, or follow all the other lengthy activities.

Update:

the *other* solution I find very helpful nowadays comes from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656862/launcher-disappeared) - the point: sometimes you have to remove (or even better: pull in a "working" backup) of your ~/.config/dconf/user file.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me!

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 this brings back the launcher, but not the dash or desktop. And after rebooting everything is dead again, and you have to repeat the procedure.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Lets be precise here: that what you probably **observed** on your system. Thing is: it seems that there can be various reasons leading to such problems; and I found that using the tweak-tool can help.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa For the record; the *other* solution I found to unity-stuck/not there problems: remove ~/.config/dconf/user ... sometimes restarting unity helps, but sometimes I have to go in and delete that file.

Answer (score 7):

If you hope into a tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd>) and run:

```
DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace
```

It will reset Unity back on tty 7 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt+</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>).

You can also try just:

```
DISPLAY=:0 unity
```

But that won't work if a windows manager is already running on display 0 (it will give you an error, just use `unity --replace` in that case).

If Unity *absolutely* refuses to restart try this:

Install `gnome-panel`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

Than run it on display 0:

```
DISPLAY=:0 gnome-panel
```

You should then have Gnome 2 style panels on your desktop, which you can use to logout.

I find Unity to be really buggy on 13.04 with my Nvidia card.. YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

I have had about 3 times where I needed the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to not loose work and it messed up...
I have nvidia also.
I would like to suggest this:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (ok, blank screen)
Type your login, hit Enter, then password (all in blank screen)
type this now:

```
sudo startx -- :1
```

will have to type password again and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
this will open a X session at <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (will jump to it automatically)
now create a new empty text file called `runBash.sh`, and type on it:

```
bash
```

save it, change its permissions to executable, and run it, you will get a truly relieving terminal that makes you remember why Linux is good ! :D

after you finish, remember to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (will end the new X session), type exit, Enter, will end the terminal (blank screen) session. if you think you missed typing exit, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and type again, don’t do it too fast.

so you can improve it, make a script to let you type as little as possible, but anyway you will still have to type a lot while the screen is blank, but it is better than nothing :)

Still looking for definitive <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> proper solution Ubuntu 12.04 + nvidia.

Comment: hi again, I have ABSOLUTELY no idea why, but for some reason, after a system freeze (I was playing a 3D game in wine), I hard reset the computer, and from a sudden I have back my text terminal ctrl+alt+f1 (but my account become unable to login thru lightdm graphical login screen, despite I still can login thru text terminal, I continue this affair on this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133733/cannot-login-via-unity-login-screen-after-upgrade-to-12-04/133754#133754)

Comment: By "blank" screen, do you men "black" or "empty"? Unless your video shows terminals in reverse video, the background is black and thus it looks much more like a black screen. Also, most often, after the Ctrl+Alt+F1 you have to hit Alt-F1, Alt-F2... to Alt-F6 to reach a terminal.

Comment: @AlexisWilke so long time... but.. as I remember, blank in a sense that you are unable to read things on screen. May be this was a secondary problem happening here also.

Answer (score 5):

It happens when you login with another tty and try, as the same user, to start X (with startx or initx) .

For example, Ubuntu runs in tty7. With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> tty1 opens. Log in as the same user, and run startx. Go back to tty7, logout and login. You only get the desktop wall paper.

To solve the problem, choose tty1, login, remove the .Xauthority file in your home directory, logout, login. Solved.

Comment: didn't work for me (also, I hadn't ever started X from another tty)

Answer (score 5):

The first answer works fine, except I needed to install Unity itself:

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

then run:

```
ccsm
```

and enable Unity :)

Comment: forget to mention it's happens on my new ubuntu 13.10, never before!

Answer (score 5):

I had pretty much the same problem under 12.04. Unity was slow with my aged GPU, so I was using Unity 2d as my desktop for months. For no apparent reason, it suddenly refused to display launchpad and title bar (for all users). Reenabling Unity in CCSM as sugggested here was part of the solution, but none of the other measures suggested here, there or in several other related threads, including, but not limited to:

- Reinstalling unity
- Reinstalling ubuntu desktop
- Removing all relevant (e.g. compiz, gconf, etc.) configuration information

helped me to completely resolve these symptoms under 12.04 (64 bit).

```
unity --reset
```

would not work for me. After delivering a variety of error and information messages, it would always hang at:

```
Setting Update "run_key"
```

as shown in the log posted in [the thread titled "unity has vanished"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1974219) for unity run with no arguments.

I noticed that the error message delivered by:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

was similar to some of the errors reported by `unity --reset`:

error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

After extensive searching, I found the following solution:

- Get the path of `libGL.so.1` by using the command `locate libGL.so.1`.
- Add a link to the library in /usr/lib/ as shown in the following example:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib
  ```

  (courtesy of [J.D. Bartlett](http://sqizit.bartletts.id.au/2011/11/07/unity-launchersidebar-missing-on-ubuntu-11-10/))
- Restart the computer.

This not only allowed both unity_support_test-p and `unity --reset` to run, it also allowed Unity 2D to start. I have no idea what caused my problems, but since creating the links above (several weeks now) I have had no further problems.

Answer (score 5):

When I accidentally upgraded from 12.04 LTS Ubuntu to 13.04, I too had to face the same issues such as missing side menu bar, no window options, not being able to switch between applications (<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>) and I couldn't even drag windows on the screen. After following so many options I ended up with the following set of commands to fix these issues.

```
sudo apt-get remove aspell #may not be relevant
sudo apt-get remove dictionaries-common
```

reboot (you can use `sudo reboot`)

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install dictionaries-common
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

reboot (you can use `sudo reboot`)

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons & disown
```

I actually removed aspell because of conflicting dependency. This might not have any correlation between this issue. I think re-installing lightdm and resetting compiz helped me in fixing this.

Answer (score 5):

**Worked for Ubuntu 16.04:**

I reset  `compizconfig` by removing its cache (actually the command makes backup, so it can be restored).

Perform the following commands and logout afterwords:

```
mv ~/.cache/compizconfig-1 ~/.cache/compizconfig-backup

setsid unity
```

**Attention:** This removes your custom Unity setup.

Answer (score 4):

If you use an acceleration graphics card alongside the default graphics card, it's possibly due to the installation of their drivers. A few updates of acceleration graphics cards drivers in systems that have two graphics card tend to present unstable behavior in some systems. I have an Nvidia card and an Intel card. It used to happen with me when I installed Nvidia drivers. Launcher and panel would disappear from the the desktop. If you use an Nvidia card, installing Bumblebee could be a temporary solution: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: I've got a ThinkPad T430u with a dedicated nvidia card but I disabled it in the BIOS and never installed any extra drivers or added 'x-swat' or edgers ppa since the intel HD4000 worked perfectly out of the box and I had been running this setup without problems for about 2 months

Comment: The behaviour of my Asus U36SD seems to confirm that it is a problem with the combination of two GPUs (Intel/Nvidia). I will post an answer explaining how I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Today I've encountered situation where user of my script has decided to launch it by placing the call to script into his `$HOME/.profile` file. As a result , Unity couldn't launch.

Scripts by nature are sequential, so `.profile` basically was waiting for the script to finish , and Unity couldn't start if `.profile` didn't finish running.

I've done the same thing,called the script from `.profile`, and received the same result - my login screen wallpaper stayed there, no dash or launcher appeared, could not right click on desktop or perform any action other than login to TTY1.

The solution was to remove appropriate line from the `.profile`. It's possible to detach a command from `.profile` using the ampersand, `<command> &` form , but the problem is that every time user opens terminal or logs in to TTY, a new instance of that command is spawned. Hence, I would *strongly advise not to launch any programs from `.profile`* unless you know what you're doing.

Link to original script and discussion here: https://askubuntu.com/a/739631/295286

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after doing `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` which broke my lightdm install for some reason. I'm running 16.04 here.

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>alt</kbd> - <kbd>F1</kbd> to get to the terminal, then:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo reboot
```

That fixed it for me after hours of pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 3):

I had this Problem, I tried a load of things and even enabled unity, but nothing worked. First, you need to open TTY (ctrl+alt+F1) and login. Now use

```
    env DISLAY:=0 gnome-terminal
```

Close TTY with ctrl+alt+F7, then use (in terminal)

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

After that, use

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks!! That worked for us finally. 

We were able to open guest session but not the regular user.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue, and solved by following using `pycharm's terminal`.

```
 - Go to my-computer -> user -> share ->  
 - open pycharm and its terminal
 - sudo apt-get update
 - sudo apt-get upgrade 
 - sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: You don't need pycharm to fix unity.  Ctrl+Alt+F1 should always give you a terminal.

Comment: this worked for me in 16.04

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, unplugging my second monitor was the fix, and then I was able to install and update the correct drivers.

Answer (score 2):

I tried many of the solutions mentioned in this thread as well as others.
Finally this worked for me:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

Thanks everybody for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and all the suggestions above failed for me.

I made the following steps:

1. Installed `kubuntu-desktop` as an user interface alternative for Unity (login via <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, then `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`). Sure, you can choose other Unity alternatives.
2. Restarted the machine and logged in via KDE.
3. Created a temp user (let's name it `alice`) with admin rights.
4. Copied my files in Alice's account.
5. Deleted the original user (including the files)
6. Created again the original user (same username, same rights)
7. Copied the files from backup.
8. Deleted the temp user (`alice`).

Then, you don't need KDE anymore. ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be better with juste `xfce` (not xubuntu-desktop!!) ? I think it's way less heavy to install (kde is so heavy) and not including *-desktop allows to ditch all "recommended" programs.

Comment: @MrVaykadji I chose `kubuntu-desktop` because I didn't remember another one. :-)

Comment: Okay, but installing kubuntu-desktop will create a hell lot of dependencies, that's all I'm saying

Comment: KDE is more powerful than xubuntu; so in a certain way: if you accept the overhead of unity and the ubuntu-desktop; then KDE might be the better choice.
On the other hand - if your focus is to have a system that reacts immediately you might want to install xubuntu in the first place.
With xubuntu, the thunar file manager pops up in a second; nautilus under unity or gnome3; or dolphin with KDE will need at least 3 to 5 seconds.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 I installed `xubuntu-desktop` but even with DE there is only the desktop background after logging in.

Answer (score 1):

I had recently edited my `.bashrc` file with the line `guake -r $(hostname)` to automatically rename tabs whenever I opened a new tab in `guake` and everything was working perfectly.  Then I restarted my computer a few days later and encountered this problem.  I can only assume that trying to start `guake` without a valid display resulted in some error that completely destroyed something in the `unity` pipeline.

So if you've recently modified your `~/.bashrc` try undoing changes.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a black background with a mouse cursor. 
The following worked for me in addition to enabling the unity plugin again via ccsm, but first I had to do the following because it didn't even properly show the desktop:
When doing unity --reset, it stopped at "show session" and some lines before it said "error loading plugin opengl", so i figured this must be related.. and it was! (just be sure to load *your* specific .so my nvidia installation had a different number of course, just do ls in the folder in described in the link

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1342339

Answer (score 1):

If the previous answers do not solve the problem, it might be that your HDD is so full that the system cannot work properly, and cannot manage to load the environment.

This can occur quite easily: you let something downloading overnight without a trigger to make it stop if the free disk space goes under a certain limit. At some point the system freezes because all the disk is full. Next morning you try to start it, and it does not load unity.

This, at least is what happened to me. The solution is simple: switch to TTY and delete manually a few things. Then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works out so far (from this thread itself, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811552/no-launcher-and-menu-bar-on-ubuntu-16-04)  or with [initctl](https://www.linuxslaves.com/2016/06/ubuntu-menu-bar-disappeared-howto-get-it-back.html)), try the following (tested on Ubuntu16.04):

1. type in terminal:

   $ software-center
2. then you can  install **Main Menu (alacarte)** in Ubuntu software
   center
3. right click on the panel and choose " **add applets to the panel**"
4. then add applet **"Menu"** to panel.

### **Beware:**

Don't install CompizConfig Setting Manager: it'll hang up your system during reboot , in the best case scenario.

Compizconfig is  a dangerous toy now:[it can break your Ubuntu installation!!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111115/no-installation-candidate-for-compiz)